# Open .HLP File At Specific Topic Using Command Line Arguments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, chm

I am attempting to open a `.HLP` Help file at a specific topic using Command Line Arguments on Windows.

I am able to successfully open a `.CHM` help file at a specific topic using the following code:

```
 /Q /E:ON /C HH.EXE ms-its:C:/Program Files/Help/Help.chm::Turnout%20Standard%20Configuration.htm
```

But the above arguments do not work for a `.HLP` Help file. Googling does not provide any results that tell us the potential `.HLP` Help file command line arguments. **Does anyone know what command line arguments should be used to open a `.HLP` Help file at a specific topic?**

Answer (score 2):

I use winhlp32.exe
It didn't come with win7, so I grabbed it from MS (I forget where exactly)
To open a specific file to a specific topic, you can use the following:

winhlp32 -kDesiredKeyword file.hlp

Where `DesiredKeyword` is replaced with the topic of interest and `file.hlp` is replaced by your filename.

As an example, the following will open up the `fabs` topic in `clib.hlp`

`winhlp32 -kfabs clib.hlp`

Source: http://support.asna.com/kb/documentation/Help_Files/AVR41/AVR/Using_Winhlp32.htm